# Error: read ECONNRESET ExpressJS and Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

Im using Knox S3 plugin in ExpressJS web application to display image uploaded in Amazon S3. When displaying the image, I sometimes have the error below. I don't have idea on the error. What caused the error?

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:539:19)
```

This is how I render the image from Amazon S3:

```
var data = '';
client.get(url).on('response', function(s3res) {
    s3res.setEncoding('binary');
    s3res.on('data', function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });
    s3res.on('end', function() {
        res.contentType('image/jpg');
        res.write(data, encoding='binary');
        res.end();
    });
}).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since drain event can happen for a stream, it is possible that you are writing faster than the other stream is capable of reading. You should use pipe that handles this for you:

```
s3res.pipe(response);
```

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

This is from nodejs documentation:
This method pulls all the data out of a readable stream, and writes it to the supplied destination, automatically managing the flow so that **the destination is not overwhelmed by a fast readable stream.**